# Changing field collation to utf-8 causes duplicate key error

Tags: mysql, duplicates

Why does simply changing the collation cause a duplicate key error?

```
mysql> describe phppos_items;
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                 | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| name                  | varchar(255) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| category              | varchar(255) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| supplier_id           | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| item_number           | varchar(255) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| description           | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| cost_price            | double(15,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| unit_price            | double(15,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| quantity              | double(15,2) | NO   |     | 0.00    |                |
| reorder_level         | double(15,2) | NO   |     | 0.00    |                |
| location              | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| item_id               | int(10)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| allow_alt_description | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_serialized         | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| deleted               | int(1)       | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
14 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> ALTER TABLE  `phppos_items` CHANGE  `name`  `name` VARCHAR( 255 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL , CHANGE  `category`  `category` VARCHAR( 255 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL , CHANGE  `item_number`  `item_number` VARCHAR( 255 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL , CHANGE  `description`  `description` VARCHAR( 255 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL , CHANGE  `location`  `location` VARCHAR( 255 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL;
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry ' ' for key 'item_number'
```

Create table:

```
| phppos_items | CREATE TABLE `phppos_items` (
  `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `supplier_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_number` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `cost_price` double(15,2) NOT NULL,
  `unit_price` double(15,2) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` double(15,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `reorder_level` double(15,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `location` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `item_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `allow_alt_description` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `is_serialized` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `deleted` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `item_number` (`item_number`),
  KEY `phppos_items_ibfk_1` (`supplier_id`),
  KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `category` (`category`),
  KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
  CONSTRAINT `phppos_items_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`supplier_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_suppliers` (`person_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1560 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |
```

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37364618/utf8mb4-unicode-ci-vs-utf8mb4-bin): The duplicate key error could stem from the fact that you are using a case-insensitive collation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When modifying the field collation, perhaps MySQL is as well trying to convert the data from latin1 to utf8. It might be that after this conversion, some of your data in the `item_number` column is containing duplicates, a space character perhaps it seems from the error.

I think these steps might help to identify which are the conflicting rows:

1. select `item_id`, `name` and `item_number` columns for all rows and keep the entries in some XLS file perhaps
2. remove the unique index on `item_number` column
3. run the `ALTER TABLE` statement that should now run successfully
4. redo step 1 and compare the output with that from step 1 and find out for which of the items is `item_number` bearing the same values

Hope this helps!

Comment: There was a space character for a row, I fixed that and it worked.

Comment: Is this the most efficient way? Recomputing the index will likely take quite some time

Answer (score 1):

To fix that, you need to know which rows have duplicate utf-8 values.

You can do that by running this query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT CONVERT(YOUR_COLUMN USING utf8mb4) AS c FROM YOUR_TABLE
) AS A GROUP BY c HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```