# utf8mb4_unicode_ci vs utf8mb4_bin

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

**So first let's see if I get it right:**

A charset is a set of symbols and encodings. A collation is a set of rules for comparing characters in a charset.

I should use utf8mb4 because mysql utf8 is a fraud, up-to-3-bytes and not the true up-to-4-bytes real utf8 charset in PHP for example.

As such, utf8mb4 is a charset and utf8mb4_unicode_ci/utf8mb4_bin are 2 of his many differents available collations.

utf8_unicode_ci do case-insensitive comparison and other special comparisons ( I heard it messes up with all the accents in french for example ) . utf8_bin is case-sensitive because it compares the binary values of the character.

**Now the questions:**

1. If for example I want to allow Case-Sensitive login names using  utf8mb4_unicode_ci I will have to do things like:

   ```
   SELECT name FROM table WHERE BINARY name = 'MyNaMEiSFUlloFUPPERCases';
   ```
2. If for example I want to allow Case-insensitive search using  utf8mb4_bin I will have to do things like:

   ```
   SELECT name FROM table WHERE LOWER(name) LIKE '%myname%'
   ```
3. So which one is better ? What about the bad things i hear about utf8_unicode_ci and the accents/other special characters ?

Thank you  :)

Comment: So to have full controll I think I will stick to binary and then custom Regex, how worse is it performance-wise ?

Comment: If you want case folding, but accent sensitivity, please file a request at http://bugs.mysql.com .

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Did you "get things right"?  Yes, Except that I think that French accents are 'correctly' compared in utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci.

Your two `SELECTs` will both to a full table scan, thereby be inefficient.  The reason is that you are overriding the collation (for #1) or hiding the column in a function (`LOWER`, for #2) or using a leading wildcard (`LIKE %...`).

If you want it to be efficient, declare `name` to be `COLLATION utf8mb4_bin` and do simply `WHERE name = ...`.

Do you think some of these equivalences and orderings are 'incorrect' for French?

```
A=a=ª=À=Á=Â=Ã=Ä=Å=à=á=â=ã=ä=å=Ā=ā=Ą=ą  Aa  ae=Æ=æ  az  B=b  C=c=Ç=ç=Ć=ć=Č=č  ch  cz
D=d=Ð=ð=Ď=ď  dz  E=e=È=É=Ê=Ë=è=é=ê=ë=Ē=ē=Ĕ=ĕ=Ė=ė=Ę=ę=Ě=ě  F=f  fz  ƒ  G=g=Ğ=ğ=Ģ=ģ
gz  H=h  hz  I=i=Ì=Í=Î=Ï=ì=í=î=ï=Ī=ī=Į=į=İ  ij=ĳ  iz  ı  J=j  K=k=Ķ=ķ
L=l=Ĺ=ĺ=Ļ=ļ=Ł=ł  lj=Ǉ=ǈ=ǉ  ll  lz  M=m  N=n=Ñ=ñ=Ń=ń=Ņ=ņ=Ň=ň  nz
O=o=º=Ò=Ó=Ô=Õ=Ö=Ø=ò=ó=ô=õ=ö=ø  oe=Œ=œ  oz  P=p  Q=q  R=r=Ř=ř  S=s=Ś=ś=Ş=ş=Š=š  sh
ss=ß  sz  T=t=Ť=ť  TM=tm=™  tz  U=u=Ù=Ú=Û=Ü=ù=ú=û=ü=Ū=ū=Ů=ů=Ų=ų  ue  uz  V=v  W=w  X=x
Y=y=Ý=ý=ÿ=Ÿ  yz  Z=z=Ź=ź=Ż=ż=Ž=ž  zh  zz  Þ=þ  µ
```

[More utf8 collations](http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html) .
[8.0 and utf8mb4 collations](http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8mb4_collations.html) .

The "520" (newer) version by not treating `Æ`, `Ð`, `Ł`, and `Ø` as a separate 'letters', and perhaps other things.

Answer (score 4):

> If for example I want to allow Case-insensitive search using utf8mb4_bin I will have to do things like:

Keep in mind that if you use `LOWER` it will ignore indexing

Answer (score 3):

For information

MySQL 8 now supports **utf8mb4_0900_as_cs** collation

- 900: UNICODE version 9
- as: accents sensitive
- cs: case sensitive

If you don't need accents and case awareness, use **utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci** (which is the default collation since MySQL 8.0.1)